# javascript if statement with css condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made a little spoiler

```
<p id="xyz" class="class" onclick="if(document.getElementById
  ('zyx') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById
  ('zyx') .style.display='block'}else{document.getElementById
  ('zyx') .style.display='none'}">Spoiler</p>
<div id="zyx">Some content</div>
```

And I am looking for a way to add a '+' if the spoiler is closed and a '-' if the spoiler is open to the Paragraph. I was thinking maybe an If statement with a condition like

```
If xyz display:none show +, else show -
```

Any thought anyone ? Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in this.innerHTML to set the html tag. Like code below:

```html
<p id="xyz" class="class" onclick="if(document.getElementById
  ('zyx') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById
  ('zyx') .style.display='block';this.innerHTML='- Spoiler';}else{document.getElementById
  ('zyx') .style.display='none';this.innerHTML='+ Spoiler';}">- Spoiler</p>
<div id="zyx">Some content</div>
```

Comment: Code dumps are not useful answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Comment: works like a charm, the innerHTML added and works erfectly , thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The better way is

```
 <p id="xyz" class="class" onclick="var zyx= document.getElementById('zyx');zyx.style.display=zyx.style.display=='none'?'block':'none';var sp=this.innerHtml;sp=sp=='Spoiler +'?'Spoiler -':'Spoiler +';">Spoiler</p>
```

Some content

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't use an `onclick` attribute to do this. Putting code in your HTML is an anti-pattern. You're already using jQuery, so let's use it.

First, we can toggle the visibility of `zyx` via `toggle`. Then, we can toggle the `+` and `-` on the paragraph using a class on the paragraph and some CSS.

```js
$("#xyz").click(function() {
  $("#zyx").toggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

```css
p .minus {
  display: none;
}
p.expanded .minus {
  display: inline;
}
p.expanded .plus {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="xyz" class="class">Spoiler <span class="plus">+</span><span class="minus">-</span></p>
<div id="zyx" style="display: none">Some content</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When the paragraph has the class `expanded`, the `-` is shown; when it doesn't, the `+` is shown.

You could also do this by toggling the visibility of the spans, changing the `+` and `-`, using `::after` content on the span...

Answer (score 0):

You need [jQuery is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) it will return true/false for selector:

```
if($('#xyz').is(':visible')){
   //if visible case add +
   $('#xyz').text($('#xyz').text() + ' + ');
}
else{
   $('#xyz').text($('#xyz').text() + ' - ');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would recommend using a pseudo `:before` element with `content: '+'` as it is specifically designed for this purpose: inserting decorative elements. When you do this you should assign a class and apply the styles on that one as the selector `.class[style*='display: none']` might cause cross browser compatibility issues. See T.J. Crowder's answer.

However, I would recommend using a different approach without JS. You can use a hidden checkbox element. This is easy to style and implement in addition to being less error-prone due to reduced complexity.

You can find a working example with commented source [here](http://codepen.io/franzskuffka/pen/LynBm).